# O365 Activity Management API - Performance for huge audit log streams

Tags: office365api

**This question is regarding the [O365 Activity Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)**

We are using the API to retrieve audit log notifications from multiple channels (AzureAD, Outlook, SharePoint, etc.) for very large tenants, meaning that we need to retrieve potentially millions of notifications over a relatively short timespan.

O365 gathers audit notifications into a series of "blobs" which then contain a number of individual notifications (JSON messages). To my understanding, which in part comes from correspondence with the API's dev. team and from [reading the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#retrieving-content), these blobs should contain a "considerable" number notifications as to function as a sort of batch approach when doing the actual web requests.

In our approach, we request blobs URLs for an interval of an hour, and then do a request for the individual blobs.

However, we have tested with a number of different tenants and different PublisherIdentifiers, but only seem to get around 2.5 messages per blob on average, no matter the total number of notifications "waiting" to be fetched.

This becomes a major issue for the larger tenants as is puts a strain on the SIEM solution running the fetcher logic (a Python service), due to the number of needed requests, and it also gives us throttling issues with the API itself.

In effect, we simply cannot fetch the audit notifications fast enough to keep up - within the retention period. Had the blobs contained more notifications per blob, we would be fine - as the total amount of data (in MBs) is not that large.

A "funny" thing is, that if we use the visual query tool within the Admin Center of the tenant, it searches and retrieves the notifications very fast.

---

**My questions**

- Has anyone had any experience with this issue, or perhaps had a better "batch performance"?
- Does anyone have any ideas as to what we could try to get a better performance?

---

As mentioned we have been in direct contact with the dev team and the program manager in Redmond. They have been very helpful with other issues we had, but they referred us to support for this specific issue - who in turn referred us to the forums / community. We currently do not have access to premium support...

**Example request for content blobs for an hour**
`https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenantid}/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Exchange&PublisherIdentifier={pub.id}&startTime=2017-12-03T10:31:24&endTime=2017-12-03T11:31:24`

When retrieving the individual blobs, we just use the URLs given to us by the above request.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid throttling by appending "?PublisherIdentifier={Tenant ID}" to the contentUri in the retrieve content get request.

[How can I add a PublisherId to a GetBlob call to the Office365 Rest API to avoid throttling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680958/how-can-i-add-a-publisherid-to-a-getblob-call-to-the-office365-rest-api-to-avoid/47693382#47693382)

Comment: Hi Ahtesham. Thanks for the answer, but we are already supplying a PublisherId

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Office 365 Management Activity API for the past 6 months. I too faced this kind of issue before. This issue will occur if you are trying to get all the audit log contents from your Office 365 tenant at a particular interval, it will result in throttling issue. For your information, it is not possible to avoid throttling issues (resource over usage) for large active tenants.

To overcome these issues, you can create and deploy a web application in cloud and register with [Office 365 Management Activity API webhook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference).

Whenever the office 365 tenant wrap the activity logs into an Azure Blob, it will immediately give the blob details to your registered Web Application. You can refer [this link](https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/walkthrough-capturing-sharepoint-online-specific-events-via-the-office-365-management-api/) to know about how to enable webhook for a Web Application. Once you received the blob detail from Office 365 tenant, extract the logs from the Azure Blob and save it in your own blob storage / store in SQL / NOSQL databases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Webhook is not an option for us, as we are just a single "plug-in" in a larger SIEM solution, living within a (fire)walled-off environment. We have, however, done some additional testing with larger clients and we actually see better "items/blob" performance. So our approach from here will simply be to have our code be aware of the throttling limit.

Comment: The "issue" as you mention is not that we try to get "all" contents, as we are very careful to only request the same time segment once. The issue arises, _if_ the number of audit events produced by the tenant exceeds what we are able to fetch via (items/blob * allowed_requests/time_unit). However, as mentioned above, we have now seen higher items/blob numbers, so this may be a theoretical discussion. We are in the process of testing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Pulling down logs would take longer than the interval of time allotted to the Python script and the script would start overlapping itself or would fall behind when trying to pull logs for a SIEM implementation.

https://github.com/IntegralDefense/o365_log_fetch

I'm a little late to this post, but by using Asyncio in Python 3.5+ as well as aiohttp, you can make concurrent calls to O365 Management API and pull down the logs much faster. I performed some testing and retrieved logs for a 13 hour window (Audit.Exchange, Audit.AzureActiveDirectory, and Audit.Sharepoint). It took around 20 minutes using 'requests' and sequentially making the API calls. After implementing Asyncio/aiohttp, the same time frame took just under 2 minutes (500,000+ individual events were pulled from the data located at several thousand content blobs/locations).

I've been running the script in 10 minute intervals and usually the script completes in < 10 seconds.

The script I pasted above also supports pagination. So if you get a content list that was truncated in the response from Microsoft, the script will keep reaching out and pulling down more content locations.

At this time, the documentation isn't up to speed, but hopefully that will be caught up soon.