# Why are my requests to Office365 management API getting Throttled

Tags: office365

I am using office365 management API to collect logs. I make a get request to the following url to get a list of content blobs.

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Exchange&PublisherIdentifier=640ababd-5eea-468d-8ffd-27ade0c4bdce&startTime=2017-12-05T10:24:23.520000Z&endTime=2017-12-05T13:24:23.520000Z
```

After I get the list of content blobs I make a get request based on the below received ContentURI

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/640ababd-5eea-468d-8ffd-27ade0c4bdce/activity/feed/audit/20171205104027168011446$20171205104027168011446$audit_exchange$Audit_Exchange
```

Some times I get 403 Client error with the following error message

```
'{"error":{"code":"AF429","message":"Too many requests. Method=GetBlob, PublisherId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}}'
```

Why are my requests being considered as part of the global quota when I am clearly sending the PublisherIdentifier information in the original request to get the list of content blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It seems the API does not accept adding the PublisherId to the individual get content call, resulting in throttling.

I am working with Microsoft to see if there is a resolution and will let you know.

See [How can I add a PublisherId to a GetBlob call to the Office365 Rest API to avoid throttling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680958/how-can-i-add-a-publisherid-to-a-getblob-call-to-the-office365-rest-api-to-avoid)